# Importing a text file containing integers into a Python list

Tags: python

Assume **TEST.txt** has contents    `3,6,8,10,9,9,5,8`

In Python, I want to import the contents of this text file into list `L`.  Here's one of many  attempts:

```
with open('TEST.txt') as f:
    L = f.readlines()
    
print(L)
```

The output is   `['3,6,8,10,9,9,5,8']`.  How can I change this to  `[3,6,8,10,9,9,5,8]` ?

Comment: Shown input and code don't produce shown output (where do brackets come from?).

Comment: @MichaelButscher `.readlines()` will produce a list of lines from the file. OP doesn't seem to understand data types, or data really, or the terminology ("import" means something completely unrelated to the question being asked).

Comment: OP: what source(s) have you been using to learn Python? It would be better if I can either point you at the appropriate information there, or get you started on something better. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a tutorial resource, but better to deal with this in the comments than the answers. The question you're asking suggests several fundamental misunderstandings and also doesn't meet the standards described in [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: `L = list(map(int, L[0].split(",")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
L = list()
with open('TEST.txt') as f:
    for s in f.readlines():
        L.extend([int(x) for x in s.split(',')])

print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
with open('TEST.txt') as f:
    L = f.read()
    
mylist = []

for i in L.split(','):
    try:
        mylist.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches for your problem the main concept is you want to convert the string into an integer. you can try>>>

```
for line in lines:
   conv_int = int(line)
```

or go for a Regular expression method like

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f: 
    fdata=f.read() 
import re 
reObj=re.compile('\d+') 
mo=reObj.findall(fdata) 
n=[] 
for i in mo:n.append(int(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = ['3,6,8,10,9,9,5,8']
foo = [int(i) for i in  f[0].split(',')]
print(foo)
```

```
[3, 6, 8, 10, 9, 9, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The code is pretty self explantory.